# textView:shouldChangeTextInRanges:replacementStrings: method crashes when NSTextStorage is edited

Tags: macos, cocoa, text, osx-lion, nstextstorage

I'm new to Cocoa programming under OSX Lion, so this is a question I cannot find answer to.
I need to modify an attributed string which is entered by the user through the `NSTextView`.
Editing may include replacement of some portion(s) of the string inside the `NSTextStorage` and addition of `NSTextAttachment` objects.
I implemented the  protocol and provided it for `NSTextView` instance as delegate.
I also implemented the method `textView:shouldChangeTextInRanges:replacementStrings:` in the next manner:

```
- (BOOL)textView:(NSTextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRanges:(NSArray *)affectedRanges replacementStrings:(NSArray *)replacementStrings{
    NSTextStorage* ts=[textView textStorage];
    [ts beginEditing];
    NSMutableString* buf=[ts mutableString];
    //make some completions
    NSRange rng;
    rng.location=0;
    rng.length=[buf length];
    [buf replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"(." withString:@"(0." options:0 range:rng];
    rng.location=0;
    rng.length=[buf length];
    [buf replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"-+" withString:@"-" options:0 range:rng];
    rng.location=0;
    rng.length=[buf length];
    [buf replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"+-" withString:@"-" options:0 range:rng];

    [ts endEditing];
    return YES;
}
```

Thus I try the next scenario: when the application is up, the user types inside the `NSTextView` some text. If he types "(." everything is going well. But when he types "-+ " (minus, plus, whitespace) - the method crashes producing this dump:

```
[NSConcreteTextStorage attributesAtIndex:effectiveRange:]: Range or index out of bounds
 (
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff95963286 __exceptionPreprocess + 198
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff8c32bd5e objc_exception_throw + 43
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff959630ba +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 106
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff95963044 +[NSException raise:format:] + 116
    4   AppKit                              0x00007fff90acb5bd -[NSConcreteTextStorage attributesAtIndex:effectiveRange:] + 121
    5   AppKit                              0x00007fff90f4cde6 -[NSTextView insertText:replacementRange:] + 840
    6   AppKit                              0x00007fff910fc891 -[NSTextInputContext handleTSMEvent:] + 2289
    7   AppKit                              0x00007fff910fe4fe _NSTSMEventHandler + 165
    8   HIToolbox                           0x00007fff89745308 _ZL23DispatchEventToHandlersP14EventTargetRecP14OpaqueEventRefP14HandlerCallRec + 1263
    9   HIToolbox                           0x00007fff89744914 _ZL30SendEventToEventTargetInternalP14OpaqueEventRefP20OpaqueEventTargetRefP14HandlerCallRec + 446
    10  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff8975b6c7 SendEventToEventTarget + 76
    11  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff89930a4d SendTSMEvent + 35
    12  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff89930dd4 SendUnicodeTextAEToUnicodeDoc + 452
    13  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff8993095e TSMKeyEvent + 629
    14  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff8976f81a TSMProcessRawKeyEvent + 2350
    15  AppKit                              0x00007fff910fbade -[NSTextInputContext handleEvent:] + 639
    16  AppKit                              0x00007fff90fc7eaf -[NSView interpretKeyEvents:] + 248
    17  AppKit                              0x00007fff90f40c65 -[NSTextView keyDown:] + 691
    18  AppKit                              0x00007fff90a20544 -[NSWindow sendEvent:] + 7430
    19  AppKit                              0x00007fff909b868f -[NSApplication sendEvent:] + 5593
    20  AppKit                              0x00007fff9094e682 -[NSApplication run] + 555
    21  AppKit                              0x00007fff90bcd80c NSApplicationMain + 867
    22  myapp                           0x0000000100001302 main + 34
    23  myapp                           0x00000001000012d4 start + 52
```

It seems that shortened string causes some out-of-bounds spill.

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix this issue? Please help.

Comment: Somehow I also have problems with this kind of issue: I am trying to add attributes asynchronously but it produces the same error. I'm really wondering where this error comes from.

Answer (score 0):

The -length method returns the quantity of characters in a NSString. The problem is that the first character is in the index 0. Try using `[buf length] - 1`. This should work.